# Consecutive count with reset based on group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to fetch consecutive count but need a reset of the "group" where the AssetName and SeverityCalc changes. Currently what I have a query which although gives me the "group" but doesnt reset when the AssetName and SeverityCalc flips but instead will take the previous group.

Any help is appreciated.
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13da30/1

**Expected**

```
Id                                             StartTime               EndTime                 Severity    SeverityCalc rn                   Group
-------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ------------ -------------------- --------------------
1803                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 07:18:07.090 NULL                    0           0            19                   1
1717                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 06:39:09.443 2022-12-13 06:54:03.027 2           1            18                   1
1633                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 05:51:22.970 2022-12-13 06:19:53.027 0           0            17                   1
1575                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 05:16:27.000 2022-12-13 05:34:34.967 1           1            16                   1
1520                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 04:39:34.947 2022-12-13 04:52:27.067 0           0            15                   1
1453                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 04:05:27.173 2022-12-13 04:16:36.963 1           1            14                   14
1411                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 03:42:04.977 2022-12-13 03:52:23.030 1           1            13                   13
1357                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 03:16:26.943 2022-12-13 03:27:25.030 1           1            12                   12
1312                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 02:56:03.030 2022-12-13 02:58:55.167 1           1            11                   11
1283                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 02:34:50.950 2022-12-13 02:37:16.940 1           1            10                   10
1251                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 02:18:15.037 2022-12-13 02:20:34.957 1           1            9                    9
1203                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 01:50:50.937 2022-12-13 02:05:38.913 1           1            8                    8
1153                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 01:22:02.977 2022-12-13 01:36:10.880 1           1            7                    7
1099                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 00:54:39.030 2022-12-13 01:06:36.903 1           1            6                    6
1002                 DT5201                    2022-12-12 23:58:14.980 2022-12-13 00:39:20.923 1           1            5                    5
938                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 23:22:47.807 2022-12-12 23:41:42.910 1           1            4                    4
873                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 22:48:11.047 2022-12-12 23:06:39.103 3           1            3                    3
813                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 22:17:16.877 2022-12-12 22:32:09.623 1           1            2                    2
732                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 21:39:53.783 2022-12-12 22:01:44.993 1           1            1                    1
1808                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 07:19:41.037 NULL                    0           0            18                   1
1741                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 06:48:43.053 2022-12-13 07:03:55.147 2           1            17                   1
1662                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 06:08:17.053 2022-12-13 06:32:07.090 0           0            16                   1
1607                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 05:32:49.083 2022-12-13 05:53:49.210 1           1            15                   1
1567                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 05:11:12.963 2022-12-13 05:19:28.983 0           0            14                   14
1525                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 04:41:46.903 2022-12-13 04:52:05.163 0           0            13                   13
1501                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 04:28:13.043 2022-12-13 04:32:38.967 0           0            12                   12
1458                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 04:08:03.143 2022-12-13 04:13:24.947 0           0            11                   11
1377                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 03:26:34.967 2022-12-13 03:58:10.987 0           0            10                   10
1302                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 02:49:19.200 2022-12-13 03:03:22.957 0           0            9                    9
1208                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 01:56:07.370 2022-12-13 02:08:05.197 0           0            8                    8
1101                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 00:54:45.287 2022-12-13 01:16:43.423 0           0            7                    7
1055                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 00:27:53.157 2022-12-13 00:37:27.030 0           0            6                    6
997                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 23:55:35.027 2022-12-13 00:13:21.237 0           0            5                    5
924                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 23:14:35.443 2022-12-12 23:25:15.227 0           0            4                    4
835                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 22:30:09.137 2022-12-12 22:43:03.050 0           0            3                    3
784                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 22:05:29.283 2022-12-12 22:11:45.197 0           0            2                    2
733                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 21:47:11.103 2022-12-12 21:52:09.037 0           0            1                    1
1340                 DT5204                    2022-12-13 03:07:18.723 NULL                    0           0            3                    3
956                  DT5204                    2022-12-12 23:34:30.887 2022-12-13 03:06:59.160 0           0            2                    2
888                  DT5204                    2022-12-12 22:57:20.410 2022-12-12 23:34:09.897 0           0            1                    1
1743                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 06:49:52.420 2022-12-13 07:05:56.393 0           0            11                   2
1624                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 05:45:08.397 2022-12-13 06:28:02.407 0           0            10                   1
1566                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 05:09:45.913 2022-12-13 05:28:14.080 1           1            9                    1
1521                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 04:39:38.037 2022-12-13 04:52:51.990 0           0            8                    8
1474                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 04:13:56.093 2022-12-13 04:24:25.970 0           0            7                    7
1405                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 03:39:03.933 2022-12-13 03:57:02.090 0           0            6                    6
1277                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 02:31:21.753 2022-12-13 03:22:19.750 0           0            5                    5
1127                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 01:07:21.947 2022-12-13 01:44:43.860 0           0            4                    4
984                  DT5205                    2022-12-12 23:49:03.973 2022-12-13 00:27:45.853 0           0            3                    3
838                  DT5205                    2022-12-12 22:31:03.827 2022-12-12 23:03:55.643 0           0            2                    2
806                  DT5205                    2022-12-12 22:15:13.863 2022-12-12 22:23:51.913 0           0            1                    1
1337                 DT5206                    2022-12-13 03:06:37.313 NULL                    0           0            1                    1
1811                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 07:22:07.773 NULL                    1           1            15                   3
1716                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 06:39:07.797 2022-12-13 06:59:25.873 1           1            14                   2
1643                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 05:58:22.310 2022-12-13 06:13:34.317 1           1            13                   1
1573                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 05:15:04.327 2022-12-13 05:30:22.347 0           0            12                   1
1524                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 04:40:11.627 2022-12-13 04:53:46.167 1           1            11                   1
1460                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 04:08:37.623 2022-12-13 04:19:05.973 0           0            10                   1
1390                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 03:32:29.767 2022-12-13 03:45:55.713 1           1            9                    4
1293                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 02:44:17.707 2022-12-13 03:09:55.640 1           1            8                    3
1194                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 01:45:31.777 2022-12-13 02:25:31.553 3           1            7                    2
1110                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 00:58:17.633 2022-12-13 01:22:13.577 1           1            6                    1
1050                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 00:24:31.573 2022-12-13 00:40:08.000 0           0            5                    2
992                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 23:53:59.310 2022-12-13 00:04:13.560 0           0            4                    1
912                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 23:09:05.367 2022-12-12 23:30:55.343 2           1            3                    3
829                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 22:26:41.213 2022-12-12 22:44:07.360 1           1            2                    2
760                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 21:44:30.710 2022-12-12 22:03:07.473 3           1            1                    1
```

**Instead get this**

```
Id                                             StartTime               EndTime                 Severity    SeverityCalc rn                   Group
-------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ------------ -------------------- --------------------
1803                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 07:18:07.090 NULL                    0           0            19                   3
1717                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 06:39:09.443 2022-12-13 06:54:03.027 2           1            18                   16
1633                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 05:51:22.970 2022-12-13 06:19:53.027 0           0            17                   2
1575                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 05:16:27.000 2022-12-13 05:34:34.967 1           1            16                   15
1520                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 04:39:34.947 2022-12-13 04:52:27.067 0           0            15                   1
1453                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 04:05:27.173 2022-12-13 04:16:36.963 1           1            14                   14
1411                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 03:42:04.977 2022-12-13 03:52:23.030 1           1            13                   13
1357                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 03:16:26.943 2022-12-13 03:27:25.030 1           1            12                   12
1312                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 02:56:03.030 2022-12-13 02:58:55.167 1           1            11                   11
1283                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 02:34:50.950 2022-12-13 02:37:16.940 1           1            10                   10
1251                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 02:18:15.037 2022-12-13 02:20:34.957 1           1            9                    9
1203                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 01:50:50.937 2022-12-13 02:05:38.913 1           1            8                    8
1153                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 01:22:02.977 2022-12-13 01:36:10.880 1           1            7                    7
1099                 DT5201                    2022-12-13 00:54:39.030 2022-12-13 01:06:36.903 1           1            6                    6
1002                 DT5201                    2022-12-12 23:58:14.980 2022-12-13 00:39:20.923 1           1            5                    5
938                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 23:22:47.807 2022-12-12 23:41:42.910 1           1            4                    4
873                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 22:48:11.047 2022-12-12 23:06:39.103 3           1            3                    3
813                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 22:17:16.877 2022-12-12 22:32:09.623 1           1            2                    2
732                  DT5201                    2022-12-12 21:39:53.783 2022-12-12 22:01:44.993 1           1            1                    1
1808                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 07:19:41.037 NULL                    0           0            18                   16
1741                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 06:48:43.053 2022-12-13 07:03:55.147 2           1            17                   2
1662                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 06:08:17.053 2022-12-13 06:32:07.090 0           0            16                   15
1607                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 05:32:49.083 2022-12-13 05:53:49.210 1           1            15                   1
1567                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 05:11:12.963 2022-12-13 05:19:28.983 0           0            14                   14
1525                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 04:41:46.903 2022-12-13 04:52:05.163 0           0            13                   13
1501                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 04:28:13.043 2022-12-13 04:32:38.967 0           0            12                   12
1458                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 04:08:03.143 2022-12-13 04:13:24.947 0           0            11                   11
1377                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 03:26:34.967 2022-12-13 03:58:10.987 0           0            10                   10
1302                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 02:49:19.200 2022-12-13 03:03:22.957 0           0            9                    9
1208                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 01:56:07.370 2022-12-13 02:08:05.197 0           0            8                    8
1101                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 00:54:45.287 2022-12-13 01:16:43.423 0           0            7                    7
1055                 DT5203                    2022-12-13 00:27:53.157 2022-12-13 00:37:27.030 0           0            6                    6
997                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 23:55:35.027 2022-12-13 00:13:21.237 0           0            5                    5
924                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 23:14:35.443 2022-12-12 23:25:15.227 0           0            4                    4
835                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 22:30:09.137 2022-12-12 22:43:03.050 0           0            3                    3
784                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 22:05:29.283 2022-12-12 22:11:45.197 0           0            2                    2
733                  DT5203                    2022-12-12 21:47:11.103 2022-12-12 21:52:09.037 0           0            1                    1
1340                 DT5204                    2022-12-13 03:07:18.723 NULL                    0           0            3                    3
956                  DT5204                    2022-12-12 23:34:30.887 2022-12-13 03:06:59.160 0           0            2                    2
888                  DT5204                    2022-12-12 22:57:20.410 2022-12-12 23:34:09.897 0           0            1                    1
1743                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 06:49:52.420 2022-12-13 07:05:56.393 0           0            11                   10
1624                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 05:45:08.397 2022-12-13 06:28:02.407 0           0            10                   9
1566                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 05:09:45.913 2022-12-13 05:28:14.080 1           1            9                    1
1521                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 04:39:38.037 2022-12-13 04:52:51.990 0           0            8                    8
1474                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 04:13:56.093 2022-12-13 04:24:25.970 0           0            7                    7
1405                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 03:39:03.933 2022-12-13 03:57:02.090 0           0            6                    6
1277                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 02:31:21.753 2022-12-13 03:22:19.750 0           0            5                    5
1127                 DT5205                    2022-12-13 01:07:21.947 2022-12-13 01:44:43.860 0           0            4                    4
984                  DT5205                    2022-12-12 23:49:03.973 2022-12-13 00:27:45.853 0           0            3                    3
838                  DT5205                    2022-12-12 22:31:03.827 2022-12-12 23:03:55.643 0           0            2                    2
806                  DT5205                    2022-12-12 22:15:13.863 2022-12-12 22:23:51.913 0           0            1                    1
1337                 DT5206                    2022-12-13 03:06:37.313 NULL                    0           0            1                    1
1811                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 07:22:07.773 NULL                    1           1            15                   11
1716                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 06:39:07.797 2022-12-13 06:59:25.873 1           1            14                   10
1643                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 05:58:22.310 2022-12-13 06:13:34.317 1           1            13                   9
1573                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 05:15:04.327 2022-12-13 05:30:22.347 0           0            12                   4
1524                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 04:40:11.627 2022-12-13 04:53:46.167 1           1            11                   8
1460                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 04:08:37.623 2022-12-13 04:19:05.973 0           0            10                   3
1390                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 03:32:29.767 2022-12-13 03:45:55.713 1           1            9                    7
1293                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 02:44:17.707 2022-12-13 03:09:55.640 1           1            8                    6
1194                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 01:45:31.777 2022-12-13 02:25:31.553 3           1            7                    5
1110                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 00:58:17.633 2022-12-13 01:22:13.577 1           1            6                    4
1050                 DT5207                    2022-12-13 00:24:31.573 2022-12-13 00:40:08.000 0           0            5                    2
992                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 23:53:59.310 2022-12-13 00:04:13.560 0           0            4                    1
912                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 23:09:05.367 2022-12-12 23:30:55.343 2           1            3                    3
829                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 22:26:41.213 2022-12-12 22:44:07.360 1           1            2                    2
760                  DT5207                    2022-12-12 21:44:30.710 2022-12-12 22:03:07.473 3           1            1                    1
```

**Code**

```
   SELECT d.Id
          ,CAST(d.AssetName as varchar(25)) 
          ,d.StartTime
          ,d.EndTime
          ,d.Severity
          ,d.SeverityCalc
          ,d.rn
          ,d.[Group]
    FROM (
             SELECT c.Id
                   ,c.AssetName
                   ,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, c.EmptyStart) AS StartTime
                   ,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, c.EmptyEnd) AS EndTime
                   ,c.Severity
                   ,c.SeverityCalc
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AssetName ORDER BY EmptyStart) AS rn
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AssetName, c.SeverityCalc ORDER BY EmptyStart) AS [Group]
             FROM (
                      SELECT [Id]
                            ,AssetName
                            ,[EmptyStart]
                            ,[EmptyEnd]
                            ,[Severity]
                            ,[L2Id]
                            ,CASE
                                 WHEN Severity = 0 THEN
                                     0
                                 ELSE
                                     1
                             END AS SeverityCalc
                      FROM [CarryBack].[Cycles]
                  ) AS c
         ) AS d
    --WHERE d.SeverityCalc = 1
    --      AND d.[Group] > 1
    --      AND d.EndTime IS NULL
    ORDER BY d.AssetName
            ,d.StartTime DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are define a pattern, wherein if the current value of severity is <> 0 and the prev value of severity is 0 then it forms part of the same group. If this condition is not met, then we start a new group.

This is a typical gaps and islands problem.

Here is a way to go about with this.

sql fiddle link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/13da30/12

```
SELECT d.Id
      ,CAST(d.AssetName as varchar(25)) Asset
      ,d.StartTime      
      ,d.SeverityCalc      
      ,sum(d.[Group]) over(partition by AssetName order by d.starttime DESC) as grp_val      
FROM (
         SELECT c.Id
               ,c.AssetName
               ,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, c.EmptyStart) AS StartTime
               ,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, c.EmptyEnd) AS EndTime
               ,c.Severity
               ,c.SeverityCalc               
               ,case when lag(c.severity) over(PARTITION BY AssetName ORDER BY EmptyStart DESC ) is NULL 
                     then 1
                     when c.Severity=0 
                      and lag(c.severity) over(PARTITION BY AssetName ORDER BY EmptyStart DESC)<>0 
                      and lead(c.severity) over(PARTITION BY AssetName ORDER BY EmptyStart DESC)<>0 
                     then 0
                     when c.Severity<>0 
                      and lag(c.severity) over(PARTITION BY AssetName ORDER BY EmptyStart DESC)=0 
                      and lead(c.severity) over(PARTITION BY AssetName ORDER BY EmptyStart DESC)=0
                      then 0
                     else 1
                  end as [Group]               
         FROM (
                  SELECT [Id]
                        ,AssetName
                        ,[EmptyStart]
                        ,[EmptyEnd]
                        ,[Severity]
                        ,CASE
                             WHEN Severity = 0 THEN
                                 0
                             ELSE
                                 1
                         END AS SeverityCalc
                  FROM Resultable 
              ) AS c
     ) AS d
ORDER BY d.AssetName
        ,d.StartTime DESC;
```